# ImportError: cannot import name '_message' from 'google.protobuf.pyext'

Tags: protocol-buffers, mlflow

I encountered the following issue when running `(py38) root@55d5bedf5958:/home/mlflow/examples# python3 sklearn_elasticnet_wine/train.py`:

```
/root/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/api_implementation.py:110: UserWarning: Selected implementation cpp is not available.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sklearn_elasticnet_wine/train.py", line 15, in <module>
    import mlflow
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from mlflow import projects  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  ...
ImportError: cannot import name '_message' from 'google.protobuf.pyext' (/root/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/__init__.py).
```

Then, I used `conda install -c anaconda protobuf` to reinstall protobuf to Version: 3.20.3, and after that, running `python3 sklearn_elasticnet_wine/train.py` worked fine.

Afterwards, I ran the command:
`(py38) root@fe284a276b34:/home/mlflow/examples# mlflow run sklearn_elasticnet_wine -P alpha=0.42`
2023/08/08 10:38:07 INFO mlflow.utils.conda: === Creating conda environment mlflow-95256b70209bdff5f1f67e9ce1aaef280fea22c4 ===
...

However, I encountered the same error again:

```
/root/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-95256b70209bdff5f1f67e9ce1aaef280fea22c4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/api_implementation.py:110: UserWarning: Selected implementation cpp is not available.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 15, in <module>
    import mlflow
  ...
ImportError: cannot import name '_message' from 'google.protobuf.pyext' (/root/miniconda3/envs/mlflow-95256b70209bdff5f1f67e9ce1aaef280fea22c4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/__init__.py).
2023/08/08 10:41:12 ERROR mlflow.cli: === Run (ID 'f783f57ae8c04881af7020eada6036cd') failed ===
```

I'm wondering why this error is occurring again. What could be the issue, and how can I resolve it?

I used `conda install -c anaconda protobuf` to reinstall protobuf to Version: 3.20.3